# Join two tables on the bases of more than one fields in each table in crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal reports.  I have two tables; One table is **`tableA`** and fields are `section`, `courseNum`, and `CourseName` and also I have second **`tableB`**  and fields have section, `courseNum`, and `StudentNumber` like below

```
tableA
section 
courseNum
CourseName 

tableB
section
courseNum 
StudentNumber
```

So I want join like this

```
tableA.Section = tableB.Section
tableA.courseNum  = tableB.courseNum
```

But I want join the two tables on the bases of more than one fields in each table in Crystal report.  How can I connect link between two fields in each table in crystal report.  I mean both are inner join or one is inner join and one field is left join.

Comment: Try using database expert

Comment: Its easy. Use Database Expert in CR. The key here is alias of table.
You will need to add the same table twice. Second time change its name i.e. give it an alias. Then use join way you want because they are completely different now.

Comment: take a look http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-multiple-tables.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to join on composite columns:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB ON tableA.Section = tableB.Section 
AND tableA.courseNum  = tableB.courseNum
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: but i don't want query.I want through crytal report window